# Google Sheets or Excel: setting the value of a remote cell from a formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, setvalue

Is there a way to create a formula in one cell that will change the value in another cell based on some criteria, without scripting?  Example: cell a1 contains a numerical value. cell b1 contains a value from a drop-down list, say, "YES,NO". If cell b1 is set to "YES" I want to remove (set to zero) the value in cell a1. What I'd like to do is have a formula in cell c1 that interrogates b1 and sets the value in a1 accordingly.  Is the only way achieve this writing code and using setValue?

Comment: You can't do it by formula. But can hide/show value using conditional formatting.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. The target column contributes to a sum for the column, so hiding it won't help me.

Answer (score 0):

you cant remove it without a script. you can visually hide it in various ways. if the A1 is subject of further sum (as in your case per your comment) the sum formula can be always altered to reflect desired output. example:

if your formula is

```
=SUM(A1, C5, D22)
```

you can do

```
=SUM(IF(B1="YES", 0, A1), C5, D22)
```

Comment: Thanks player0.  Good shout, but my sheet has around 1000 rows and I rely upon the sum of column A (SUM(A1:A1000) ....so, I can't really use a condition within a "SUM" formula.   I fancied that a script is the only way to do what I want to do, but I thought I'd put it out there in case someone had a fancy way to use formulas with indirect references or something along those lines :-) . Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following on the cell you need the calculation (or zero) on:

```
=IF (B1="YES",0,SUM(A:A))
```

Using the given formula, you would do the SUM calculation for the whole Column A if the value on B1 is "YES", if not, then a 0 would be placed on the cell you put the formula on.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the command does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Thank you! The answer has been updated.